# Integrating Dokuwiki in a Drupal site

Tags: php, authentication, drupal, dokuwiki

Does anyone have experience or suggestions on how to integrate Dokuwiki with a Drupal site? What I want to achieve is for a user to only have to log in only once with Drupal and be able to access the wiki when they navigate to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before, I used this tutorial to allow dokuwiki to grab the drupal credentials.  It's for phpbb but the same general principal applies.

http://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:integrate_with_phpbb?s[]=users

Answer (score 1):

If anybody wants to do this for Drupal 7, I've written a Dokuwiki plugin which does it... Here's the link: http://n00bsys0p.co.uk/projects. Direct any feedback or bug/feature requests to the contact page on the main site!